# Is there exist counterparts in .NET world for the application client Container ,Web Container, EJB Container and application server in Java world?

Tags: java, c#, containers

Is there exist counterparts in .NET world for the application client Container ,Web Container, EJB Container and application server in Java world?

If the answer is no , may I know why .NET doesn't need those things?

Comment: Microsoft does, indeed, have a [middleware strategy](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Microsofts-middleware-strategy-puts-developers-first). The "Distributed Internet Applications (DNA) architecture" would be analogous.

Comment: A more modern container from Microsoft is the Azure AppFabric which they demoed on Build 2016.